# Select a specific page of @page

Tags: html, css

So I am making a document with html and css for printing, when I try to select a specific page of the entire document with:

```
@page :nth(5) {
background-color: aqua;
}
```

it doesn't select the page (in this example the background color)

What I want to achieve is to select specific pages of a entire document.

Comment: do you use any specific CMS? Like Drupal, wordpress? If not, you could make different css files for each page, though I don't really recommend it. You can also add different classes to the body of each page.

Comment: thanks for the idea but I am using flying soucer (html to pdf) and I am doing it all in one single file. The thing is I have a lot of content and I want to choose one specific page of  the entire document (independent of the content)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page) (or for the spec, [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule)). regarding the use of the `@page` rule:

> You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be
>   ignored.

As you can see, changing the `background-color` property will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, and is there another way of selecting a page of a the entire document?

Comment: Yes, that's what `@page` does.

Comment: MDN is just one community resource. It is not *the* documentation.

Comment: Ahh okey, so there is no way for background-color or background image?

Comment: @BenM But when I try:
 
`   @page :first {
    @top-center { content: element(headerFirst) }
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    }`

It seems to work